# Rank position Order By two columns

Tags: laravel

I have a problem with my rank position score ! actually i would like to order by "nb_point_classement" witch is "Pts column" and also order by "nb_difference" witch is "DIFF clolumn". But when in combine the two order by one of them don't work. I explain you :) ..

Here is the rank that i would get :

[image]

Here the rank that i get with the combination of both order by

I would like to order by the best "Pts" column and by the best Diff column to the minimum

[image]

```
 $classements = Classement::where(['compet_id' => $competition->id])
            ->orderBy('nb_point_classement' , 'DESC')
            ->orderBy('nb_difference' , 'DESC')
            ->take(10)
            ->get();
```

Hope someone could help me :D thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 0):

The way order by works with multiple orders is that the first order by takes priority. The only instance that the second order by comes into account is if there is a tie with the first order by. For instance, if you have two `Equipe` with `Pts` of 5, then it would look for which had a higher `nb_difference`; otherwise it will always order by `Pts` first.

It would be very helpful for you to show how you would like the outcome to look but it sounds like those are two separate queries.

You really need to have both:

```
$classementsByPts = Classement::where(['compet_id' => $competition->id])
            ->orderBy('nb_point_classement' , 'DESC')
            ->orderBy('nb_difference' , 'DESC')
            ->take(10)
            ->get();
```

and

```
$classementsByDiff = Classement::where(['compet_id' => $competition->id])
            ->orderBy('nb_difference' , 'DESC')
            ->orderBy('nb_point_classement' , 'DESC')
            ->take(10)
            ->get();
```

I'm not sure how you are presenting the data, whether this is an api call or a view but you should pass both of those collections into your view.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, how could i do this ? maybe i need to make a query inside another query to get the good result ?

Comment: I've updated my answer, maybe provide what your controller looks like for that endpoint.

Comment: thanks a lot for your help ! so i need to query , how could i display only one rank now ? because i need to have one rank and only one :/